# Short story in which Hitler is a jovial professor, having been accepted at an art or architectural school

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alternate-history

I was told about a short story in which people are being given a tour of a campus in Germany by a jovial professor, who isn't named until the end.  The historical twist is that Hitler (born 1889) was accepted when he applied to study art, instead of being rejected in 1907, as in real life, and eventually became a professor.  It's possible that he could have gone to architectural school, as he was advised, but unable to do.

The story had to be published prior to 1985, but probably not earlier than 1960.

Comment: The closest I can find (in that it at least meets the criteria of "Hitler being accepted into the Academy of Arts") is Sabine Wiedemeyer-Schwiersch's "Requiem für einen Stümper" (Requiem for a Dilettante), but that is from 1999 and reflects on Hitler's career as a painter in an obituary rather than having him as a character himself.

Comment: @Basya actually it does not (I have the book next to me and I just looked it up).

Comment: I accidentally deleted the wrong comment -- Eike Pierstorff was referring to my deleted comment which suggested: [The World Hitler Never Made: Alternate History and the Memory of Nazism](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1086417.The_World_Hitler_Never_Made) might help; he studies books and short stories about alternate histories having to do with Hitler. He may mention the one you are looking for.

Comment: This is a popular theme apparently. I put in an answer with one example, and then found another. They are both novels though; I have not found a short story yet. *Is it possible you may be misremembering and it was a novel*?

Comment: @Basya I would also have thought that this is a popular idea, but Rosenfeld actually has only one example of it (which is the German short story in my first comment) and the two other novels I found where much later than the specified time frame. Of course that does not mean there aren't other short stories out there, but given how comprehensive Rosenfeld's book is otherwise, it seems less of a trope than one would assume (e.g. compared to the number of "let's kill Hitler with a time machine" and similar stuff).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - good point about the dates; I forgot to check...

Comment: There is "[Catch that Zeppelin!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_That_Zeppelin!)" (1975) by Fritz Lieber, but in that story,  H is an airship designer and only an amateur artist.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.  I was going to say that it had to be in English, since the person who told me that only reads English, BUT, she does have a habit of talking about things that she read about as if she read them.   It sounded to me like s short story, if that was the entire plot, but maybe not.  The 1985 date is pretty firm, but I suppose that it could have been an earlier story that she read later. (She was 15 in 1960)    The absolute latest it could have been is 2015, but I'm pretty sure she told me about it before she moved out of state.

Comment: @Basya - I'll try to find Rosenfeld's book.   Maybe it will lead somewhere.   She thought it was funny, so I don't think that she got it from there, but maybe if someone else told the story to her.   I could be misremembering.  I have always hoped that I'll never be asked to testify at a trial.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - Maybe, it she got the story wrong.   I suppose someone in the obituary could have said that he gave them a tour.

Comment: @Spencer  I've found "Catch the Zeppelin" in a couple of old anthologies.   I'll try to find a copy that isn't $65.00 for a used hardback!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are remembering *La part de l'autre*? Except that it is a novel, not a short story, and it has two parallel stories -- one of his real life and one as you described:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_part_de_l%27autre):

> La Part de l'autre ("The One Part or The Other", also called "The
> Alternative Hypothesis") is a 2001 alternate history novel by
> Éric-Emmanuel Schmitt, the plot serving to illustrate the writer's
> ideas of Moral Philosophy. It consists of a fictionalized biography of
> Adolf Hitler, sticking to the known facts of Hitler's life, in
> parallel with the fictional alternative biography the world-famous
> painter known as "Adolf H." - the person which Hitler could have
> become.
>
> According to Schmitt, "The minute which changed the course of world
> history" is the moment when a member of the jury of the Vienna Academy
> of Fine Arts uttered the words "Adolf Hitler: Failed".[1] The
> historical character, angry and bitter at being rejected by the
> academy, feeling that he deserved to be accepted and that he must have
> been the victim of some kind of conspiracy, begins to descend the path
> that would eventually lead him to be the rabble-rousing leader of the
> Nazi Party and the dictator of Nazi Germany.
>
> Conversely, in the alternative reality where the jury member said
> "Adolf Hitler: Accepted", the young Hitler is deliriously happy to
> enter the academy, where he discovers a world of feelings that his
> less fortunate double would never know - eventually leading to his
> becoming the highly successful painter Adolf H.

OK, this one is a long shot -- it apparently has not been translated to English, and it was only published in 2001.  I'll leave it here for reference though; it might help someone searching for something similar.

Found by searching 'alternate history "Hitler" professor art'